# How do I extrude so that it doesn't deform my object?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, edges, workflow, extrude

I have this object that I'm trying to model but there's that extruded object that I'm trying to recreate. The problem that I keep running into is that when I tried loop cutting the object it becomes deformed. Does anyone have any idea on how I can create this effect without it being deformed? Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello it's not clear how your object looks like, what you're trying to extrude, etc, maybe share your file?